# What makes something a dynamic data structure?

Tags: c#, data-structures

So I'm pretty confused about data structures. What makes a data structure dynamic? Is dictionary a dynamic data structure? What are some examples of dynamic data structures?

Comment: Where did you hear that term? What research have you done so far?

Comment: Context is key... A c# dictionary has a well defined data type.   Opposed to the dynamic type in c# or types in languages such as JavaScript.

Comment: @AndrewPiliser My teacher was throwing around that term and I was just confused. Can you define that?

Comment: Why not ask them if they are using a term you don't know? They might be using it in a very different way than someone here. Not all terms are specific and universally agreed upon.

Comment: Was your teacher just standing there yelling "dynamic data structure! Waaa-hooo!", or did he provide any examples or discuss any particulars?

Comment: MSDN: [Dynamic versus Static Data Structures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa227514(v=vs.60).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

**What makes a data structure dynamic?**
Any data structure that can change its size at run-time, this means you don't need to know its size to store values in it.

For example:

```
  int[] numbers; 
  numbers = new int[10];  //not dynamic data structure, you need to define the size before able to store data in it.
```

`List` is dynamic data structure because you can just add items in there without having to pre-define its size.